GeeksForGeeks Online Judge | Python3 | Recursion: Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)
Question Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/1
Env: Python3
Submission of the below implementation resulting in an error: Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)

Increasing the recursion limit to 1_000_000 did not work

Problem Constraint: 1 ≤ V, E ≤ (10**4)
Implementation:
class Solution:
    def perform_dfs(self, source, adj, visited: set, dfs_order: list):
        """Recursively traverses the graph from the given source (vertex)
    
        @param source: vertex (starting from 0)
        @param adj: adjacency list of the graph; each vertex (as the index) mapped to its list of connected nodes
        @param visited: a set to keep track of the visited nodes
        """
        # BASE CASE:
        if source in visited:
            return dfs_order
        # MAIN LOGIC:
        visited.add(source)
        dfs_order.append(source)
        for adj_node in adj[source]:
            self.perform_dfs(adj_node, adj, visited, dfs_order)
        # return
        return dfs_order


    #Function to return a list containing the DFS traversal of the graph.
    def dfsOfGraph(self, V, adj):
        """Solution 1: Recursive
    
        *** Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)
        Test Cases Passed: 1110 /1120
    
        for input: V = 919; E = 12003
    
    
        - We have been given the num of nodes in the graph
        and the adjacency list for each node.
        - The graph is UNDIRECTED and CONNECTED
    
        Time Complexity: O(V + E), since each node will be visited at least once (CONNECTED GRAPH)
        where, V = num of nodes (vertices)
        and E = num of edges
    
        Space Complexity: O(V), req for tracking the visited nodes
        """
    
        visited = set()
        dfs_order = []
        return self.perform_dfs(0, adj, visited, dfs_order)


This function is not the function required by GfG. How do you use it?

Cannot reproduce this. Voting to close.

My apologies, I should have mentioned the whole code @SergeBallesta.

Well, you're potentially recursing very deeply. As deep as the longest path the algorithm traverses, which could have every single node on it. sys.setrecursionlimit only changes the safety checks, not the actual limits of what's safe.

I just submitted that code on GfG. There is no such error.

Strange! The solution is passing now without any errors.
